# Slow Sum with Subscripts

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

*Edit*: My original question implicated `D` in the problem, but it seems unrelated, so I've removed that part of the question.

I am writing a function that uses functions involving subscripts and an open-ended `Sum`.  It's unreasonably slow.  Here's a minimal example (the real situation is much worse):

```
Sum[
  -2 Exp[-(xx - Subscript[x, k])^2/(V + Subscript[Vx, k]^2)] Subscript[n, k] (xx - Subscript[x, k])/(V + Subscript[Vx, k]^2)
, {k, nsp}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
Sum[
  -2 Exp[-(xx - subscript[x, k])^2/(V + subscript[Vx, k]^2)] subscript[n, k] (xx - subscript[x, k])/(V + subscript[Vx, k]^2)
, {k, nsp}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Well, good thing I'm not using `Superscript`, because that's 10X worse:

```
Sum[
  -2 Exp[-(xx - Superscript[x, k])^2/(V + Superscript[Vx, k]^2)] Superscript[n, k] (xx - Superscript[x, k])/(V + Superscript[Vx, k]^2)
, {k, nsp}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

So, is there some way to tell `Sum` not to bother trying anything fancy?  And what's with the 100-fold range of timing of otherwise identical code?

*N.B.*: these timings change on rerunning the same code due to some kind of caching

Comment: This is not a speed-up from "without subscripts" but after using "without subscripts" just apply `x_[j] -> Subscript[x, j]]`.

Comment: Use `Format[x[j_]] := Subscript[x, j]` and similar, then the indexed variables will display as subscripts in the output.

Comment: You could use `Block` to temporarily redefine `Sum` and `Subscript` with your own versions. These need only implement minimal functionality

Comment: @JimB Yeah I thought of that, but applying that back-transformation eats up basically all of the time-savings.

Comment: Using @BobHanlon 's comment and reversing `Sum` and `D` seems to cut the time in half on my machine (but your mileage might vary):  `Sum[D[Exp[-(xx - x[j])^2/(V + Vx[j]^2)] n[j], xx], {j, nsp}] // AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: Why not wrap Inactive around your sum, i.e., `D[Inactive[Sum][...], ..]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll `Inactive` is one of the many holes in my knowledge of the Wolfram language, so thanks for pointing that out.  It works with these toy examples, we shall see if it help with my actual problem!

Comment: @CarlWoll Yeah, what took >15 minutes now takes 2 seconds -- just what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the `Sum` option I was looking for is `Method -> "Procedural"`:

```
Sum[
  -2 Exp[-(xx - Subscript[x, k])^2/(V + Subscript[Vx, k]^2)] Subscript[n, k] (xx - Subscript[x, k])/(V + Subscript[Vx, k]^2)
, {k, nsp}, Method -> "Procedural"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]