# Symbolic derivative over summations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

How to take the symbolic derivative of an expression over two summations? Below is the expression:

```
e = 0.5*
Sum[Subscript[N, 
 ij]*((Subscript[g, i]*
       Overscript[Subscript[II, ij], \[HorizontalLine]] - 
      Subscript[g, j]*
       Overscript[Subscript[II, ji], \[HorizontalLine]])^2/
   Subscript[\[Sigma], N]^2 + (1 - Subscript[g, i])^2/
   Subscript[\[Sigma], g]^2), {i, 1, n}, 
   {j, 1, n}]
```

I need to take derivatives with respect to `Subscript[g, i]` and `Subscript[g, j]` and to equate to `0`. Please note there is a summation of `i` and `j`.

What I tried was:

```
Dgi = D[e, Subscript[g, I]]
```

But it takes forever and doesn't produce the results.

Below is without `Subscript` and `Overscripts` in expressions.

```
e = 0.5*Sum[
NN[i, j]*((g[i]* II[i, j] - g[j]* II[j, i])^2/\[Sigma]N^2 + (1 - 
      g[i])^2/\[Sigma]g^2), {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

Derivative,

```
Dgi = D[e, g[i]]
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Avoid `Subscript` and `Overscript`s in expressions. They look pretty, but they make a mess of everything else. Use e.g. `g[i]` instead of Subscript[g, i]

Comment: For two subscripts, can I use it as `II[I,j]` or `II[i][j]`?

Comment: Maybe adding `Method -> "Procedural"` to your `Sum` helps?  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250239/slow-sum-with-subscripts/

Comment: Generally it's nicer to do two subscripts as `a[i, j]` instead of `a[i][j]` if only for the reason that built-ins like `Array` conventionally give generalize from one argument to two arguments in the first manner instead of the second (test out `Array[a, {2,2}]`)!

Comment: Also a word of caution: the capital `i` (`I`) in the original expression is a built-in symbol meaning the imaginary unit. It will not be treated as a variable (usually).

Comment: Also, you might already be aware, but just in case, you might want to use `1/2` instead of `0.5` when doing symbolic reasoning; numbers entered in decimal format are treated as inexact machine numbers, and certain simplifications you might want to do later might not work as expected, as the presence of `0.5` will automatically convert symbolic mathematical constants like `Pi` into approximate numeric form!

Comment: In MMA version 8.0 both of your versions with and without Subscript work very well. But regard, in your first attempt,you have a typo, write `Dgi = D[e, Subscript[g, i]] ` instead of Dgi = D[e, Subscript[g, I]].

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why, but for some reason, the overall factor of `NN[i,j]` inside the sum is causing an issue. **I think this is a bug.** Distributing this factor over the term inside seems to make it work—but it's a bit worrying that this happens! Might be worth submitting feedback about it, and maybe someone else here might have better insight and a more robust workaround.

#### A workaround

In the meantime, here's an ad-hoc workaround: define a helper function to `Expand` the first argument of any sums in the expression, and apply that to `e` first.

```
ExpandSums[expr_] := (expr /. (Sum[x_, y__] :> Sum[Expand[x], y]))

D[ExpandSums[e], g[i]]
```

(Note that the summation index `i` will be replaced with `K[1]`, as it should, lest the outer `i` explicit in `D[ExpandSums[e], g[i]]` interfere with the one inside `e`!)

#### Make the workaround automatic

If you want to make the above application of `ExpandSums` happen *automatically* each time you evaluate `D`—and effectively "build it into the definition of `D`"—you can do so with the following trick (which is for preventing the definition from being applied recursively forever):

```
Unprotect[D];

interceptDDef = True; Protect[interceptDDef];

D[x_, y___] := 
 Block[{interceptDDef = False}, D[ExpandSums[x], y]] /; interceptDDef

Protect[D];

(* Test *)

D[e, g[i]]
```

(This trick is not original to me; it's been known for a long time! I think it's even mentioned in [this book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/63584).)

---

#### More info on why this is happening:

It seems to not be a problem of Mathematica's differentiation, but of how `Sum` and `KroneckerDelta` interact and automatically expand to strange piecewise expressions.

Consider

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[i,k], {i, 1, n}]
```

The above input is obtained as an intermediate expression, I believe, in evaluating

```
D[Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}], a[k]]
```

We can see that this is the case by inactivating `KroneckerDelta`:

```
Block[{KroneckerDelta = Inactive[KroneckerDelta]}, D[Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}], a[k]]]
```

A minimal case exhibiting the problem you've brought to attention seems to be

```
expr = Sum[f[i] (a[i] + a[j]), {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];

(* Causes Mathematica to hang: *)

D[expr, a[k]]
```

The same issue seems to be happening:

```
ok = Block[{KroneckerDelta = Inactive[KroneckerDelta]}, D[expr, a[k]]]

(* Out: an expression involving KroneckerDelta's! *)
```

And Mathematica effectively hangs when re-activating the `KroneckerDelta`'s:

```
(* Hangs: *)

Activate @ ok
```

So, it seems like that's where the issue "really" is. I'm not sure yet how to turn automatic expansion of `Sum`s of `KroneckerDelta`'s into piecewise functions off...

---

#### Another bug to watch out for!

Note that using a `Method` option for `Sum` is inappropriate here, as for some reason—quite unexpectedly—`D` can't handle differentiation with respect to composite symbols (e.g. `a[i]` as opposed to just `a`) for `Sum`s with a `Method` value, even `Automatic`! Contrast

```
D[Sum[a[i],{i,1,n}], a[k]]

D[Sum[a[i],{i,1,n},Method->Automatic], a[k]]
```

Now consider—a worse bug—the following:

```
D[Sum[a[i],{i,1,n},Method->Automatic], a[i]]
```

It seems Mathematica doesn't know how to perform the alpha-conversion needed for the `Sum` in this case, and misinterprets `a[i]` as unbound by `Sum`, and uniform across all `i`.

I'm going to submit a separate ticket for this, but thought it was worth it to warn you off using `Method`s in symbolic sums, as apparently doing so is buggy when it comes to differentiation.

Comment: Thanks for your help!